# yii2 add new label but logout not working

Tags: yii2

Hello i am new with the FrameWork and my problem concern my nav  i use the default navigation.

1: when my user is logged i dont want to see this tab :

```
[‘label’ => ‘Créer un compte’, ‘url’ => [‘/site/signup’]]
```

and the login

so i made this for my probleme and it work well :

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
? [
       ['label' => 'ouverture de session', 'url' => ['/site/login']],
       ['label' => 'Créer un compte', 'url' => ['/site/signup']]
   ]
```

2:
when i am logged is work fine but now when is time to loggout is receive a error message : The ‘label’ option is required. [‘/site/logout’] not working…

see my full code :

```
<header id="header">
        <?php
        NavBar::begin([
            'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/img/logo.png', ['alt' => 'Charte De Crypto', 'style' => 'height: 48px;margin-right: 10px;']) . "<h3 class='h3mobile;' style='font-weight: bold;color: white;'>" . Yii::$app->name . "</h3>",
            'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            'options' => ['class' => 'mynav  fixed-top']
        ]);
        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav '],
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                ['label' => 'À Propos', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
                ['label' => 'Nous Contacter', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
                //['label' => 'Créer un compte', 'url' => ['/site/signup']],
                // ['label' => 'Dire', 'url' => ['/site/dire']],
                Yii::$app->user->isGuest
                    ? [
                        ['label' => 'ouverture de session', 'url' => ['/site/login']],
                        ['label' => 'Créer un compte', 'url' => ['/site/signup']],
                    ]

                    : '<li class="nav-item">'
                    . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'])
                    . Html::submitButton(
                        'Se déconnecter (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                        ['class' => 'nav-link btn btn-link logout']
                    )
                    . Html::endForm()
                    . '</li>'
            ]
        ]);
        NavBar::end();
        ?>
    </header>
```

code error : https://postimg.cc/7GXL6hnT

so what i need to do for fixing this problem ?

i have tried a lot of thing with chatGPT but not working.

the problem continue when i click on the button logout...

```
  : '<li class="nav-item">'
                    . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'])
                    . Html::submitButton(
                        'Se déconnecter (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                        ['class' => 'nav-link btn btn-link logout']
                    )
                    . Html::endForm()
                    . '</li>'
```

the button work well if the code is like the original like this :

```
    Yii::$app->user->isGuest
                    ? 
                    ['label' => 'ouverture de session', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
                    : '<li class="nav-item">'
                    . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'])
                    . Html::submitButton(
                        'Se déconnecter (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                        ['class' => 'nav-link btn btn-link logout']
                    )
                    . Html::endForm()
                    . '</li>',
            ]
        ]);
```

but with the second line added like this the button loggout not working...

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
                    ? [
                        ['label' => 'ouverture de session', 'url' => ['/site/login']],
                        ['label' => 'Créer un compte', 'url' => ['/site/signup']],
                      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your block 'echo Nav::widget(...' to

```
$items = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ['label' => 'À Propos', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
    ['label' => 'Nous Contacter', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
    //['label' => 'Créer un compte', 'url' => ['/site/signup']],
    // ['label' => 'Dire', 'url' => ['/site/dire']],
    [   'label' => 'ouverture de session',
        'url' => ['/site/login'],
        'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest
    ],
    [   'label' => 'Créer un compte',
        'url' => ['/site/signup'],
        'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest
    ]
];

if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $items[] = '<li class="nav-item">'
                . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'])
                . Html::submitButton(
                    'Se déconnecter (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    ['class' => 'nav-link btn btn-link logout']
                )
                . Html::endForm()
                . '</li>';
}

echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
    'items' => $items
]);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. i have tried  is working at 99%  but if a click on logout  i receive : 

Method Not Allowed (#405)
Method Not Allowed. This URL can only handle the following request methods: POST.

Comment: Ok, have changed my answer. Your mistake was to put array of arrays in ternary operator 'Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?' and yii2 cant handle it. So in your case it is  better to build $items separately of Nav::widget() calling.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I finded the solution :)  if can help someone  plz see below ;

```
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/img/logo.png', ['alt' => 'Charte De Crypto', 'style' => 'height: 48px;margin-right: 10px;']) . "<h3 class='h3mobile;' style='font-weight: bold;color: white;'>" . Yii::$app->name . "</h3>",
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => ['class' => 'mynav  fixed-top']
    ]);
    $items = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'À Propos', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        ['label' => 'Nous Contacter', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
    ];
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $items[] = ['label' => 'ouverture de session', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
        $items[] = ['label' => 'Créer un compte', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];
    } else {
        $items[] = '<li class="nav-item">' 
        . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'])
        . Html::submitButton(
            'Se déconnecter (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
            ['class' => 'nav-link btn btn-link logout']
        )
        . Html::endForm()
        . '</li>';
    }
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav '],
        'items' => $items,
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?